# geo local google Maps API business results foursquare like for iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios4, geolocation

Im using google map api and im being limited to 8 searches everytime im searching for a business place and its not very accurate( meaning that there is a nearby mcdonalds that did not appear on the search). Does anyone know of any good tutorials on how to increase the amount of results nd how is it possible to set the results so that they appear automatically providing a list of the names of all nearby business within a radius kind of like foursquare or facebook places?

Comment: Why not use FourSquare's API to get a list of places?

Comment: doesnt Foursquare use google's API to make theirs? besides whats the difference?

Comment: No, FourSquare doesn't use Google's API. The difference is that it does exactly what you've asked for, to the point where you mentioned FourSquare as the kind of thing you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are either using the deprecated Google Local Search API, or the GoogleBar for Maps API v2. If you switch to Maps API v3 you can use the new Places library, which will return 20 results per query in JSON format so that you can render them on and alongside the map as you please:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Many thanks,

Thor.